# read() on Linux and page-aligned buffers

Tags: c, linux, unix, optimization, posix

I was implementing an efficient text file loader and found some good advice from the author of GNU grep in this post:
http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

One of things he suggests is to do read() calls of page aligned blocks of data into page aligned buffers. Apparently this allows the kernel to avoid some extra buffering.

I've been searching and I haven't heard anyone else back up this claim. Is it true that calling read() into a page aligned buffer (perhaps allocated with mmap/posix_memalign etc..) is actually more efficient? If its not true, is it something that used to be true? Does it heavily depend on the underlying file system or other factors like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly dependent on a number of factors that profiling would reveal.  The trick is that I suspect it would be easy to code up a solution that works well in one environment and unexpectedly work horrible in another - thus a highly efficient general purpose solution is unlikely.  Profiling a given solution may work well with test data and crap with a future real set.

Comment: interesting.. did you test can compare on your platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, `read()` will read into a kernel buffer, then copy it to user space.  This extra copy is what is being discussed.

Linux supports "direct I/O" via the O_DIRECT flag to `open()`.  This will skip kernel buffering and read directly into the userspace buffer.  However, this direct I/O requires aligned accesses and buffers.  So I don't think the author of that post meant that magic happens when you're aligned, but rather that if you align carefully, you can use "closer-to-the-metal" techniques to extract more performance.

`mmap()` is a much easier way to get the same effect.  When the mapping is first set up, no I/O happens.  When the user first accesses a page in the mapping, a page fault is triggered, which the kernel handles by allocating the user's page and performing the I/O to fill it.  No copy.  But again, the I/O happens in page-sized chunks, on page-aligned boundaries.

Whether this is a big deal or not depends on how fast memory copies happen relative to the I/O, and what proportion of CPU time is spent copying rather than doing real work.  A web server, for instance, often doesn't even have to look at what it's reading: it just writes it out again out a socket (which incurs another copy).  That's why a bunch of work has gone into "zerocopy" techniques like system calls `sendfile()` and `splice()`.  These are specialized workloads.  Normally, the buffering is too small an effect to worry about.

Comment: Worth noting that when *writing* you'll want the writes to be page-aligned. Otherwise, you'll end up with at least one page that's partially written, and in order for Linux to store that partially written in the page cache it must read the unwritten bytes from the disk. Via this method, a `write()` may produce a synchronous read, and no writes (until later)!